# How to get users original logon and logoff event from security log?

Tags: c#, windows, active-directory

In windows security event log has many logon(4624) and logoff(4625) events. How to get the users original log on and its log off events. Please any one help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: You'll need to search, looking at the event log entrys's parameters for the right user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Event Log thinks in terms of sessions, instead of physical logon or logoff as we think. For instance, a logoff event may trigger when a resource the logged-in user was using timed out due to inactivity. [Not sure if you can rely](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericfitz/archive/2007/05/08/the-trouble-with-logoff-events.aspx) on Windows Event Log for historical reporting of physical logon/logoff events.

Another option could be the Active Directory's [lastLogoff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676822%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [lastLogon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676823%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) properties associated with the user object. But then it will give you only the most recent logoff or logon time. If that fits your scenario, see [this example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/565593/How-to-get-the-REAL-lastlogon-datetime-from-Active) for how to read that property.

For historical reporting you will at least need to make sure that auditing is turned on. Then you can add simple one-line logon and logoff scripts which write to a logfile every time a user physically logs in or out. See [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/556015) for details on that.

Lastly, you can also use a 3rd party product called [Active Directory Audit](http://www.manageengine.com/products/active-directory-audit/) by ManageEngine.